# Can't update array in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

İ find the specific book according to its Id. But i cant update that collections owner array.
That array already has some values, but i want to update it with the new values below.

```
 Book.find({_id: "5423"},function(err,usr){
    usr[0].update($set:{owner:["123","145"]});
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is given in the [official documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24push). Here is an example which can be executed in Mongo shell:

```
b1 = { 'name' : 'Introduction to MongoDB', owners : [1, 10] }
b2 = { 'name' : 'SQL for Dummies', owners : [5] }

db.Books.save(b1)
db.Books.save(b2)

book = db.Books.find().next() // just picking first available book
db.Books.update({ _id : book._id }, { $pushAll : { owner : [123, 145]} })
```

Note that MongoDB will NOT return you and updated document (again, this is how DB was designed and how it works).

Comment: You want to use `$pushAll` here instead of `$push` or the array itself would be pushed onto the `owner` array as one new element.

Comment: Thanks for updating, JohnyHK.

Comment: @BasicWolf when i do res.json(usr), json returns the past values. Am i doing a syntax mistake?

Comment: `usr` is the result of `find()`. Because of the asynchronous nature of MongoDB it will not be changed in this scope. I recommend you to read some general docs about MongoDB to understand how it works and what are the best practices.